# Error using Box SDK on Azure Functions

Tags: azure, box, azure-functions

I am getting a **"Could not load file or assembly 'Box.V2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ddda8fe64dde1ac3' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified"** error in **Azure Functions**. Any ideas on what the problem might be?

I am using the package.json file to have Azure Functions pull in the references and hook them all up as described in the docs.

> When you upload a project.json file, the runtime gets the packages and automatically adds references to the package assemblies. You don't need to add #r "AssemblyName" directives. Just add the required using statements to your run.csx file to use the types defined in the NuGet packages.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp

My package.json file:

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "BouncyCastle": "1.8.1",
        "BouncyCastle-PCL": "1.0.0.6",
        "Box.V2": "2.14.0",
        "Box.V2.JWTAuth": "1.2.0",
        "Microsoft.Bcl": "1.1.10",
        "Microsoft.Bcl.Async": "1.0.168",
        "Microsoft.Bcl.Build": "1.0.14",
        "Microsoft.Net.Http": "2.2.29",
        "Newtonsoft.Json": "6.0.2",
        "Nito.AsyncEx": "2.1.3",
        "System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt": "4.0.2.206221351"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

run.csx using statements:

```
using global::Box.V2;
using global::Box.V2.Config;
using global::Box.V2.Exceptions;
using global::Box.V2.JWTAuth;
using global::Box.V2.Models;
```

Full Exception:

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException : Exception while executing function: Functions.GetTelogisFormInstancePdf ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'Box.V2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ddda8fe64dde1ac3' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

   at Submission#0.Run(HttpRequestMessage req,TraceWriter log) at  : 84 

   End of inner exception

   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target,Object[] arguments,Signature sig,Boolean constructor)

   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,Object[] parameters,Object[] arguments)

   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj,BindingFlags invokeAttr,Binder binder,Object[] parameters,CultureInfo culture)

   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.DotNetFunctionInvoker.InvokeCore(Object[] parameters,FunctionInvocationContext context)

   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionInvokerBase.Invoke(Object[] parameters)

   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`1.InvokeAsync[TReflected](Object[] arguments)

   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.InvokeAsync(IFunctionInvoker invoker,Object[] invokeParameters,CancellationTokenSource timeoutTokenSource,CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource,Boolean throwOnTimeout,TimeSpan timerInterval,IFunctionInstance instance)

   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithWatchersAsync(IFunctionInstance instance,IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameters,TraceWriter traceWriter,CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource)

   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(??…
```

Comment: Looks like a sign of version mismatch. Can it be that same dependency is referenced twice from different packages with different versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is misleading and I had to end up overriding BoxJWTAuth in order to make it work.  The details of this error can be found here:  https://github.com/box/box-windows-sdk-v2/issues/297

Comment: Seems like you found the solution. I'll wait until Box addresses it. I'll mark this as the Answer for now.

Answer (score 2):

The error is clearly stating that it can't find the assembly:

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'Box.V2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ddda8fe64dde1ac3' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

And while you show in your .csx that you have using statements to include the namespaces, no where do you show that you actually [reference the external assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#referencing-external-assemblies)

As described in the above linked documentation:

`If you need to reference a private assembly, you can upload the assembly file into a bin folder relative to your function and reference it by using the file name (e.g. #r "MyAssembly.dll").`

Make sure you get the path correct; I had to ensure the `bin` folder was within my path where the function was - the shared assembly approach didn't work for me.

I also suggest that perhaps an easier approach than dealing with csx and referencing assemblies is to ditch csx all together and use pre compiled functions as described in this [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/03/16/publishing-a-net-class-library-as-a-function-app/). Then you get full compile time resolution of assemblies and proper intellisense that you just don't get with the CSX files.